# How to Calculate Covariance of Branching Process

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a branching process $\{X_n\}$, where $X_0=1$. How would I go about calculating the covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(X_j,X_i)$ for $i\leq j$?

Not sure how to start, so hint would nice to get me on the right track. I was given a hint that using the concept of conditional probabilities might be helpful here but I don't see why?

Comment: Hint: $Cov(X_i,X_j)=E(X_iX_j)-E(X_i)E(X_j)$. Now, $E(X_i)$ and $E(X_j)$ are easy. Next, $E(X_iX_j)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X_i=k)E(X_iX_j\mid X_i=k)=\cdots$.